# Solving System of Linear Differential Equations

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a set of 4 linear equations:
$$\begin{align}&\frac{\partial \widetilde{u}}{\partial t} + \bar{u}\frac{\partial \widetilde{u}}{\partial x} = -\frac{1}{\bar{\rho}}\frac{\partial \widetilde{p}}{\partial x}\\
&\frac{\partial \widetilde{w}}{\partial t} + \bar{u}\frac{\partial \widetilde{w}}{\partial x} = -\frac{1}{\bar{\rho}}\frac{\partial \widetilde{p}}{\partial z} - \frac{\widetilde{\rho}}{\bar{\rho}}g\\
&\frac{\partial \widetilde{u}}{\partial x} +\frac{\partial \widetilde{w}}{\partial z} = 0\\
&\frac{\partial \widetilde{\rho}}{\partial t} + \bar{u}\frac{\partial \widetilde{\rho}}{\partial x} + \widetilde{w}\frac{\partial \bar{\rho}}{\partial z} =0
\end{align}$$

where:

$u(x,z,t) = \bar{u}+\widetilde{u}(x,z,t)$

$w(x,z,t) = \widetilde{w}(x,z,t)$

$p(x,z,t) = \bar{p}(z)+\widetilde{p}(x,z,t)$

$\rho(x,z,t) = \bar{\rho}(z)+\widetilde{\rho}(x,z,t)$

with $\bar{u}$ being spatio-temporally constant.

I know that I can solve it by substitution, but i was hoping that i could solve it matricially, but i am not too sure on how to proceed.

If I want a solution based on $\widetilde{w}$, could I write the matrix as:

\begin{array}{cccc|c}
A & \widetilde{w} & 0 & \bar{\rho}^{-1}\partial_x & \widetilde{u}\\
0 & A\widetilde{w} & \rho^{-1} g & \bar{\rho}^{-1}\partial_z & 1\\
\partial_x & \partial_z\widetilde{w} & 0 & 0 & \widetilde{\rho} \\
0 & \widetilde{w}\partial_z\bar{\rho} & A & 0 & \widetilde{p} \end{array}

with $A = \partial_t+\bar{u}\partial_x$ ? Or there is a correct way to do it. The idea is to arrive at the following equation:

$A^2(\frac{\partial^2 \widetilde{w}}{\partial z^2} + \frac{\partial^2 \widetilde{w}}{\partial x^2}) +\frac{g}{\bar{\rho}}\frac{\partial \bar{\rho}}{\partial z}\frac{\partial^2 \widetilde{w}}{\partial x^2} = 0$